# How to share on Pinterest

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I have a JavaScript function for sharing on Pinterest like this:

```
function shareOnPinterest(url, desc, coverImage){

var str = "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&media=" + coverImage + "&description=" +
desc;

window.open(str, "_blank");         

}
```

The URL seems to be working fine but when I click Pin It button it doesn't pin to the board.

I have a reference to this Pinterest JavaScript on my page too.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Is there anything I did wrong or is there any other way to share on Pinterest?

Thanks.

Comment: your `shareOnPinterest` function does not require `pinit.js`. Where do you find this script ?

Comment: I found the url from http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/ here and it says need to include pinit.js on the page and script I did it myself.

Comment: You misunderstand it. You should look into the codes in `Pin It` button instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're wanting... a button for your webpage or to simply pin images?

This codes works to pin images:

```
javascript:void((function(){var%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)})());
```

Comment: thanks m8 I found the problem it was because of the sharing text. I remove the "&" from sharing text and now its working :) cheers